# Is attaining real transparency with imagettftext and imagecolortransparent possible?

Tags: php, gd

When using imagettftext with an image rendered transparent via imagecolortransparent, the border of the text seems to have blended with the original background color (black) instead of the transparency, thus creating an outline of the text as seen here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLSkK.png as opposed to using imagestring, here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPRqC.jpg

Now I'm not sure if there's a better way to combine images so they're created transparent from the start, or if there's some other transparency method I'm not aware of.  Here's the relevant PHP code I'm using:

```
if ($type) {
  $icon = imagecreatefrompng("images/" . $type . ".png");
}
else {
  die('Invalid type.  Valid types are: arcane, elysian, divine, spectral');
}
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(128, 25);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $black);
imagecopymerge($img,$icon,0,0,0,0,28,25,100);

imagettftext( $img, 16, 0, 30, 20, $col, $font, $input_num );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $img );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagecolortransparent` will never work very well because of anti-aliasing---the background color near outlines are not true black. Your best bet will be to use PNG images with transparent areas in the first place instead of ones with the black background..